# Age old Google Map & Tabs, not loadings?

Tags: google-maps, tabs

The below code should work but for some reason the second tab is not loading the map correctly.

The map resize doesn’t seem to be working correctly, but i cannot figure out why its not loading. It peridoicaly  loads and when it does the second tab doesn’t load the marker in the middle of the page either?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   


                //Default Action
                $(".tab_content").hide();
                $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); 
                $(".tab_content:first").show(); 

                //On Click Event
                $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
                    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
                    $(this).addClass("active"); 
                    $(".tab_content").hide(); 
                    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
                    $(activeTab).fadeIn();  
                    return false;
                });



                function initialize()
                {


                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5388795,-0.057876099999930375);
                    var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(51.54141329999999,-0.08070509999993192);

                    var myOptions =
                    {
                        zoom: 15,
                        center: latlng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };

                    var myOptions2 =
                    {
                        zoom: 15,
                        center: latlng2,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };

                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas1"), myOptions);

                    var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), myOptions2);

                    var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker(
                    {
                        position: latlng,
                        map: map,
                        title:"Test Title"
                   });

                    var myMarker2 = new google.maps.Marker(
                    {
                        position: latlng2,
                        map: map2,
                        title:"Test Title"
                    });


                    $(".tabs a").click(function() {
                        $(".tab_container > div").css({'display':'block'});
                        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

                    });
                }                   

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        })
```

Comment: How are your tabs defined (what does your CSS/HTML look like)? Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (although I find it hard to believe there is not a duplicate of this somewhere).  A [Fiddle with your posted code works](http://jsfiddle.net/4r8jeb7u/) (but doesn't have tabs)

Comment: Updated your fiddle with my tabs... http://jsfiddle.net/4r8jeb7u/1/

Seems to load the map but the marker is not in the middle... Doesn’t load the map outside fiddle though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to trigger the resize event on "map2" also.  And you have to do it after the div has been displayed.  You also have to set the center of the map once the map has the correct size (otherwise it appears in the upper left corner).

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4r8jeb7u/2/)

```
//On Click Event
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
    $(".tab_content").hide(); 
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
    $(activeTab).fadeIn();  
    return false;
});

$(".tabs a").click(function () {
    $(".tab_container > div").css({
        'display': 'block'
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    google.maps.event.trigger(map2, 'resize');
    setTimeout(function () {
        map.setCenter(latlng);
        map2.setCenter(latlng2);
    }, 100);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps Api Have Been Updated. Checkout new Api versions.